# Using UIImageView with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6, sdwebimage

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to implement SDWebImage in my TableViewController but I'm having some errors due to my UiImageView that I'm not able to detect the problem and I need some help with that. I hope you can find something because I'm lost at the moment.

I'm getting the following error:

***No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'***

**The app is working and the cache is working fine but I'm getting that error.**

Why is this error happening if I have already set my "carImage" to UIImageView? How can I solve it?

**CarTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
    cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
    cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

// ERROR    [cell.carImage sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];
    NSData * imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2];
    UIImage * carPhoto2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];

    cell.profileImage.image = carPhoto2;

    return cell;
}
```

That's my **CarTableViewCell.h**:

```
@interface CarTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *carImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *makeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *modelLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *likes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *comments;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *refuser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImage;

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you check that Library Search Paths ... or was it Framework Search Paths? for your Project + Target + TestSuite build settings all point to the SDWebImageFramework ? I recall last time I was missing the path to the framework for my TestSuite and it complained about framework not found.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the UIImageView category, so the compiler can see it:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Comment: I have already done that but I still have that error. Thanks @0x52

Comment: For me the IBOutlet was UIView instead UIImageView

Comment: I had same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing the header file that contains the sd_xxxx category methods you're trying to call.

Try this:

```
@implementation SomeClass

-(void)doSomething {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view doSomethingCool];
}

@end
```

You will get the same type of error.

Comment: I can click in my sd_ method and I get redirected to the file inside my project. Why is this still not working?